# Cosmos DB selective regional replication

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, replication

We are planning to use cosmos db single master deployment where all master data are maintained from a single region. The application is spread across various regions and we need to provide read access to the individual regions. However we would like to have filtered replication as not all regions will be interested in all data in cosmos DB. Is there any way to use selective region specific replication? I am aware that we could use Cosmos DB trigger and then have function app etc to replicate traffic but that is an overhead in terms of maintenance and monitoring. Hence would be interested to know if we can make use of any native functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in geo-replication mechanism is completely transparent to you. You can't see it and you can't do anything about it. There is no way to do what you described without writing something custom.

If you really want to have selected data replicated then you would need to do the following (**It's a terrible solution and you should NOT go with it**):

- Create a main source of truth Cosmos DB account. That's "single master" that you described.
- Create a few other accounts in whichever region you want.
- Use a Cosmos DB trigger Azure Function or the Change Feed Processor library to listen to changes on the main account and then use your filtering logic to replicate them into the other accounts that need to use them.
- Use a different connection string per application based on it's deployment environment

What's wrong with just having your data replicated across all regions though? There are no drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. We don't want to replicate all data from security and scope perspective. Also wanted to mention that it seems the solution you described is similar to what I described in terms cosmos db trigger (perhaps nomenclature was not right). Could you please mention what could be the possible issues with this approach?

Comment: Maintainability is the biggest one. You would have to have multiple accounts, with multiple connections strings for multiple regions and regions specify deployment settings and database provisioning configuration. If you are happy to maintain all that then go for it.

Comment: ok, I was thinking that there could be issues from cost and performance perspective. Thanks for your response - agree there could be maintainability issues that need to be thought about. Also there will be quite some custom codes that need to maintained and monitored..

Comment: @NickChapsas is there any updates on how to partial replicate data in CosmosDB? We have this particular use case where some data cannot be replicated to some regions due to GDPR and some other restrictions, but we would like to have multi region read/write.